# Proving that the set $R := \{ x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x^\alpha y^\beta \geq F_0 \}$ is convex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

> Let
>
> $$R := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x^\alpha y^\beta \geq F_0 \}$$
>
> where $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$ and $F_0 > 0$. Is set $R$ convex?

We know that the intersection of convex set is convex. Now $\{x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$ is clearly convex. So I need to show that the set $\{x^\alpha y^\beta \geq F_0\}$ is convex. I may show that the function $f(x,y) = x^\alpha y^\beta$ is concave, because this implies that for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x : f(x) \geq c\}$ is convex. But I am not able to show that the function f is concave.

Comment: I had made an arithmetical error in my former answer, which I have now deleted. However, the fact that the determinant of the Hessian is only non-negative when $\ \alpha\ $ and $\ \beta\ $ satisfy more restricted conditions than mere positivity, means that $\ x^\alpha y^\beta\ $ is not necessarily concave (which [K B Dave's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516454/proving-that-the-set-r-x-geq-0-y-geq-0-x-alpha-y-beta-geq-f-0/3516685#3516685) shows you don't need anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You actually only need to know that $$F(x,y)=x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$$
is *quasi*-concave, i.e., that the superlevel sets $\{(x,y)\mid F(x,y)\geq F_0\}$ are convex. Concave functions are quasi-concave, and quasi-concave functions are preserved under monotone maps, so it suffices to show that $$\ln F(x,y)=\alpha\ln x + \beta \ln y$$ is a concave function. But that can be shown directly.

Comment: Thank you, computing the hessian I see that the function is concave. But why do you say that we can see it  'directly'? Thank you.

Comment: I mean computing the hessian of the log of the initial function